# Is there a way to set deployment target for a Xcode playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode12

I've upgraded to MacOS 11 (Big Sur) Beta 4. And Xcode 12 beta 4.

I have a Swift playground with Combine publishers:

```
Just([1,2,3])
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self) // Make the compiler pick up new API in MacOS Big Sur
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
```

After upgrading my playgrounds start to fail with the message: **"'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer".** The swift compiler dosen't indicate any errors in the code. And the code works fine if placed in a normal Xcode command line app project.

The error can be mitigated by enclosing the publisher in a availability check like, `if #available(macOS 11.0, *) { }` in the playground.

I'm assuming this is a bug and I've filed an issue with Apple.

Or is this expected behavior? And if it is ... is there a way to hint to a playground what deployment target to assume? If it's not correctly picking up the actual version of the operating system it's running against.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi weenzeel, could you find a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, but a bit hidden...

Open your 'MyName.swiftpm' package by right clicking it in Finder and select 'Show Package Contents'.
Then you should see a 'Package.swift' file.

Open it with a simple text editor and change the 'platforms' entry (e.g. to iOS 17):

```
    platforms: [
    .iOS("17.0")
]
```

Comment: This works, but sadly the file states:
"WARNING: This file is automatically generated. Do not edit it by hand because the contents will be replaced."
So this is no solution in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to set the deployment target for a Xcode playground. Playgrounds are designed for rapid experimentation and learning, and their API is limited compared to full-fledged Xcode projects. However, there are workarounds you can use depending on your specific needs:

1. Target a Specific iOS Version:
   While you can't directly set the deployment target, you can choose the iOS version you want to simulate when running the playground.
   Go to the Playground Settings (gear icon) in the navigation bar.
   Under Platform, select the desired iOS version. This ensures the code you write targets that version and avoids potential compatibility issues.
2. Adjust Language Features for macOS Playgrounds:
   For macOS playgrounds, you can influence the available language features through Swift packages.
   Install Swift packages that only support the macOS version you're targeting. This indirectly limits the playground's capabilities to align with the chosen macOS deployment target.
3. Use Separate Xcode Projects:
   If you need precise control over the deployment target and full project features, create a separate Xcode project alongside your playground.
   Develop core functionality in the project, then import specific parts into the playground for interactive exploration. This approach allows for more control over deployment targets and project structure.
   Remember: Playgrounds are not meant for production-ready code. If you need strict deployment target control, consider using traditional Xcode projects for development and testing.

Comment: There is no "Deployment Target" section for a Swift Playground (.swiftpm) file.  There are only "General", "Signing & Capabilities", and "Packages" sections.  General just contains "App Settings" and there is no option to set a Deployment Target as in a typical Xcode project.